# Azure Auto Scale set - Ubuntu - updates

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-storage, autoscaling, azure-autoscaling-block

I'm slowly dying over the complexity of Azure Auto Scaling Sets, and i think it might just be lack of knowledge.

Is it really neccesary for me, each time i want to make changes to etc. nginx configurations, or pull a git repository to:

1. Spin up an existing image
2. Make changes to that image
3. Degenerate the VM and create a new image
4. Use PowerShell or RestAPI to provision the Auto Scale Set with the new image
5. Hope for success or repeat

Is there no way for me to simply SSH onto my main instance, make the changes, and apply for a provisioning ?

Issent there any easier way to actually setup and manage my infrastructure behind the auto-scaling? Or is it neccesary to spend an additional 30-40 minutes, for a 2 minutes config change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it really neccesary for me, each time i want to make changes

Yes, as we know, Azure VMSS auto scale up will create new instance with that image, so we can't make changes in instances, we should make change in image.

> Is there no way for me to simply SSH onto my main instance, make the
>   changes, and apply for a provisioning ?

For now, Azure only support make changes in image.

> is it neccesary to spend an additional 30-40 minutes, for a 2 minutes
>   config change?

Maybe we can give your feedback here, all of the feedback you share in this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: So. Is there at least a simple (like simple) guide on smartest, most rationel and productive ways to change, create and provision with these images? Following the "Custom image guide" is a cumberstone task and takes forever.

Comment: @Jonasm We can create a unmanaged disk VM and follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized) to create custom image.

Comment: I'm aware, as i commented following this guide leads to us having to spin up the image, degeneralise, save and update, which is a very tiresome task. Is there any faster, more productive way to work with the images, in an Azure Scale set?

Comment: @Jonasm Sorry, for now Azure does not support some faster ways to create new image :(

Comment: @Jonasm Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)

Comment: Hi Jason, i got a confirmation that there were no easier way, so yes, i believe it was usefull. Thank you :)